# Matplotlib Animation: Animating Circles position from scipy array

Tags: python, animation, matplotlib

I am trying to animate position of Circles in matplotlib and don't think have got it right

my data is 2D matrix size ((1000,4))   each row contains the y location of 4 circles, x is always 1

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot
from matplotlib import animation

data = np.zeros((1000,4))

fig=pyplot.figure()
ax=pyplot.axes([0,40,0,40])
circle1=pyplot.Circle((data[0,0],1),0.2,fc='y')
circle2=pyplot.Circle((data[0,1],1),0.2,fc='g')
circle3=pyplot.Circle((data[0,2],1),0.2,fc='r')
circle4=pyplot.Circle((data[0,3],1),0.2,fc='b')

def init():
    circle1.center=(data[0,0],1)
    circle2.center=(data[0,1],1)
    circle3.center=(data[0,2],1)
    circle4.center=(data[0,3],1)
    ax.add_patch(circle1)
    ax.add_patch(circle2)
    ax.add_patch(circle3)
    ax.add_patch(circle4)
    return circle1, circle2, circle3, circle4

def animate(i):
    for state in data:
        circle1.center=(state[0],1)
        circle2.center=(state[1],1)
        circle3.center=(state[2],1)
        circle4.center=(state[3],1)
    return circle1, circle2, circle3, circle4
anim=animation.FuncAnimation(fig,animate,init_func=init,frames=1000,blit=True)

pyplot.show()
```

The following error is thrown:

```
  File "C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\matplotlib\transforms.py", line 2242, in inverted
    return CompositeGenericTransform(self._b.inverted(), self._a.inverted()    )
  File "C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\matplotlib\transforms.py", line 1680, in inverted
    self._inverted = Affine2D(inv(mtx), shorthand_name=shorthand_name)
  File "C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\numpy\linalg\linalg.py", line 520, in inv
    ainv = _umath_linalg.inv(a, signature=signature, extobj=extobj)
  File "C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\numpy\linalg\linalg.py", line 90, in _raise_linalgerror_singular
    raise LinAlgError("Singular matrix")
LinAlgError: Singular matrix
```

Comment: can you post the full traceback of your error? What is `data`?

Comment: data is integers in scipy array arrange as ((1000,4))

Comment: LinAlgError: Singular matrix

Comment: please, check the edit I've made in your code, now it is throwing the `Singular matrix` error...

Comment: My data = numpy.zeros((1000,4))  but the shape and size of numpy.arange(1000).reshape(250,4) are different

Comment: I fixed the edit in your question (you could have fixed it too)

Answer (score 1):

I fixed a few parts in your code.

1. I put some values in `data` so that circles animate.
2. You probably wanted to put the center of circles in `data` at each time step, then `for` loop in `animate` is not necessary.
3. It seems that `animation` function does not work with `patches` on Mac if you don't use `Qt4Agg` backend. If you use Mac, you probably need to add the first two lines below.

---

```
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('Qt4Agg')

import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot
from matplotlib import animation
from math import sin

data = np.zeros((1000,4))

data[:,0] = [20*(1+sin(float(x)/200)) for x in range(1000)]
data[:,1] = [20*(1+sin(float(x)/100)) for x in range(1000)]
data[:,2] = [20*(1+sin(float(x)/50)) for x in range(1000)]
data[:,3] = [20*(1+sin(float(x)/25)) for x in range(1000)]

fig=pyplot.figure()
ax = pyplot.axes(xlim=(0, 40), ylim=(0, 40))

circle1=pyplot.Circle((data[0,0],1.0),0.2,fc='y')
circle2=pyplot.Circle((data[0,1],1.0),0.2,fc='g')
circle3=pyplot.Circle((data[0,2],1.0),0.2,fc='r')
circle4=pyplot.Circle((data[0,3],1.0),0.2,fc='b')

def init():
    circle1.center=(data[0,0],1)
    circle2.center=(data[0,1],1) 
    circle3.center=(data[0,2],1)
    circle4.center=(data[0,3],1)
    ax.add_patch(circle1)
    ax.add_patch(circle2)
    ax.add_patch(circle3)
    ax.add_patch(circle4)
    return circle1, circle2, circle3, circle4

def animate(i):
    # for state in data:
    circle1.center=(data[i,0],1)
    circle2.center=(data[i,1],1)
    circle3.center=(data[i,2],1)
    circle4.center=(data[i,3],1)
    return circle1, circle2, circle3, circle4


anim=animation.FuncAnimation(fig,animate,init_func=init,frames=1000,blit=True)

pyplot.show()
```

Comment: thanks it still raises the LinAlgError: Singular matrix error as before.